# Change format/language for sonata_type_date_picker in sonata Admin

Tags: symfony, datepicker, sonata-admin

I use sonata_type_date_picker to add a datepicker in my sonata admin form : 
http://sonata-project.org/bundles/core/master/doc/reference/form_types.html#sonata-type-date-picker-and-sonata-type-datetime-picker

I need to change the format (default : MM/DD/YYYY) to a french format, and the language also.
I do this :

```
$formMapper->add('datedebutContrat', 'sonata_type_date_picker', array(
    'label'=>'Date de prise de fonction',
    'dp_language'=>'fr',
    'format'=>'dd/MM/yyyy'
));
```

But the result is always in english.

Thanks

Comment: any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 2):

You should do it by extending the template **SonataAdminBundle::standard_layout.html.twig** and adding into the javascript bloc:

```
<script src="{{ asset('/bundles/sonatacore/vendor/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/src/js/locales/bootstrap-datetimepicker.fr.js') }}"></script>
```

or use request locale as in the **SonataAdminBundle::standard_layout.html.twig** around line 61

In your Bundle, you extend
example **my_layout.html.twig**

```
{% extends 'SonataAdminBundle::standard_layout.html.twig' %}
{% block javascripts %}
{{ parent() }}
<script src="{{ asset('/bundles/sonatacore/vendor/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/src/js/locales/bootstrap-datetimepicker.' ~ app.request.locale|replace({'_':'-'}) ~ '.js') }}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

And add in **sonata_admin** section in your **config.yml**:

```
sonata_admin:
    templates:
        layout:         YourBundle::my_layout.html.twig
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to install SonataIntlBundle and configure it so that the Local will be French:

```
sonata_intl:
    timezone:
        locales:
            fr:    Europe/Paris
```

Comment: This does not change anything for me :(